# dplyr invalid subscript type list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have run into an error in a script I am writing that only occurs when I have `dplyr` running. I first encountered it when I found a function from `dplyr` that I wanted to use, after which I installed and ran the package. Here is an example of my error:

First I read in a table from excel that has column values I am going to use as indices in it:

```
library(readxl)
examplelist <- read_excel("example.xlsx")
```

The contents of the file are:

```
1   2   3   4
1   1   4   1
2   3   2   1
4   4   1   4
```

And then I build a data frame:

```
testdf = data.frame(1:12, 13:24, 25:36, 37:48)
```

And then I have a loop that calls a function that uses the values of `examplelist` as indices.

```
testfun <- function(df, a, b, c, d){
  value1 <- df[[a]]
  value2 <- df[[b]]
  value3 <- df[[c]]
  value4 <- df[[d]]
}

for (i in 1:nrow(examplelist)){
  testfun(testdf, examplelist[i, 1], examplelist[i, 2], 
      examplelist[i, 3], examplelist[i, 4])
}
```

When I run this script without `dplyr`, everything is fine, but with `dplyr` it gives me the error:

```
 Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Why would having `dplyr` cause this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think MKR's answer is a valid solution, I will elaborate a bit more on the *why* with some alternatives.

The `readxl` library is part of the `tidyverse` and returns a tibble (`tbl_df`) with the function `read_excel`. This is a special type of data frame and there are differences from base behaviour, notably *printing* and *subsetting* (read [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/24/tibble-1-0-0/)).

> Tibbles also clearly delineate `[` and `[[`: `[` always returns another tibble, `[[` always returns a vector. No more `drop = FALSE`

So you can see now that your `examplelist[i, n]` will return a tibble and not a vector of length 1, which is why using `as.numeric` works.

```
library(readxl)

examplelist <- read_excel("example.xlsx")

class(examplelist[1, 1])
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

class(examplelist[[1, 1]])
# [1] "numeric"

class(as.numeric(examplelist[1, 1]))
# [1] "numeric"

class(as.data.frame(examplelist)[1, 1])
# [1] "numeric"
```

My workflow tends towards using the `tidyverse` so you could use `[[` to subset or `as.data.frame` if you don't want tibbles.

Answer (score 2):

I can see this issue even without loading `dplyr`. It seems the culprit is use of `examplelist` items. if you print the value of `examplelist[1, 2]` then it is 1x1 dimension data.frame. But the value of `a, b, c and d` are expected to be a simple number. Hence if you change `examplelist[i, 1]` etc using `as.numeric` then the error will be avoided. Change call of `testfun` as:

```
testfun(testdf, as.numeric(examplelist[i, 1]), as.numeric(examplelist[i, 2]), 
          as.numeric(examplelist[i, 3]), as.numeric(examplelist[i, 4]))
```

Comment: This works, but I still don't understand why loading `dplyr` would change the value of `examplelist[1, 2]` (which I now have checked with and  without `dplyr`). I expect when subsetting a data frame with [a, b] that it will simplify the result (or at least that is what Advanced R told me). Why would loading `dplyr` change that behavior, and how?